# Looping function to ask for input until valid

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this function:

```
def read_file(fname):
        f = open(fname, 'r')
        s = f.read()
        return s
```

It is supposed to take an input(the name of the file to read) and save it to a variable called portfolio. However, if I specify a file that does not exist, I get an IOError, and I can't seem to figure out how to deal with it through try/except.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with dealing with it through try-except?

Comment: I just can't get it to ask for another input if the previous file was not found.

Comment: I didn't know I could edit the title. Thanks @poke

Comment: And remove the comment, to never mind the title, when it's fixed xD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *stop* it from giving you the `IOError` for a nonexistent file. If you could, how would you even know that you had to do anything, like ask for another filename?

What you *can* do is *deal with* that error—in any way you want, like asking for another filename.

For example:

```
while True:
    fname = raw_input('Gimme a filename')
    try:
        contents = read_file(fname)
        break
    except IOError as e:
        print('Sorry, {} gives me an error: {}'.format(fname, e))
```

Now, when you run this, it'll keep asking for a filename until you give it one that you can read. If you give it a file that doesn't exist (or one that you don't have read permissions for, or that's locked for exclusive access, or that's stored on a bad disk block, or anything else that can cause an error), it'll ask you again.

Comment: Came across a bit wrong, I didn't want to avoid the error, just wanted to deal with it through try/except, but I couldn't come up with anything.
This worked like a charm though, modified it a bit to fit my program and its the bomb.

What is 'as e' by the way? Is it another version of python?

Comment: @DavyKarlsson: `as e` isn't another version of Python; it's perfectly valid 2.7 code, and in fact the old-fashioned alternative (`except IOError, e:`) has been deprecated since 2.6. If you're learning from some source that wants you to do it the other way, you need to find a newer source.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this?

```
success = 0
while (success == 0):
    try:
        #get your input
        read_file(fname)
        success = 1
    except(IOError):
        success = 0       #totally unnecessary I guess, but whatever
```

It's been a while since I did real development, so that might not be how try/except actually works in Python, but you get the idea.